# What is the difference between running maven goals from console and from jenkins

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, sonarqube

What is the difference between executing build with `mvn clean install` and running jenkins job with maven goal `clean install`?

I'm running:

`mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.jacoco.itReportPath=target/jacoco-integration.exec`

and it works as expected but adding following maven goal to jenkins works differently.

`sonar:sonar -Dsonar.jacoco.itReportPath=target/jacoco-integration.exec`

I figured out, that jenkins executes builds as jenkins user, but is that all?

Comment: What do you mean by 'works differently'?

Comment: It doesn't executes my integration tests.

Comment: Did you check the console output of the jenkins job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly:

- Jenkins executes using `jenkins` user (or whatever you configured).
- Jenkins spawns everything in it's own process space, and changes to that process's environment are not persisted.
- Jenkins makes sure that no processes are left running after the job execution completes.